# How to correct hashCode() methos to correctly use HashSet collection

Tags: java, hashset, hashcode

To assure that our equals and hashcode() are well implemented we have to assure the following rules

- Reflexivity
- symmetry
- transitivity
- consistency
- non-nullity

But my following implementation violate the rule consistency (x will never be equals to it self if I modify its fields) so what I have to do to make this test run correctly ?

```
public class TestHashCode {

public class Point {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // generated code by netbeans IDE
    }

}

@Test
public void testEquals() {
    Point x = new Point(1, 1);
    Set<Point> pointsAsSet = new HashSet<>();
    pointsAsSet.add(x);
    x.x = 3 ;
    Assert.assertTrue(pointsAsSet.contains(x));
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You can't mutate properties of a member of a `HashSet` (that participate in the implementation of `equals` or `hashCode`) and expect it to work.

Either don't mutate such properties, remove the element from the `HashSet` before you mutate it, and re-add it later:

```
Point x = new Point(1, 1);
Set<Point> pointsAsSet = new HashSet<>();
pointsAsSet.add(x);
...
pointsAsSet.remove(x);
x.x = 3 ;
pointsAsSet.add(x);
...
Assert.assertTrue(pointsAsSet.contains(x));
```

As an alternative, if you had some unique immutable property in your `Point` class, you could use it as a key in a `HashMap` (for example `HashMap<Integer,Point>`), and then you won't need your `Point` class to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: Exactly, might propose `public final int x; public final int y;` - immutable objects, allowing sharing.